# AngularJS uib-datepicker-popup. Начало дня

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, timezone

```
<input type="text"
                       class="form-control"
                       uib-datepicker-popup
                       ng-model="paymentSchema.showDate"
                       is-open="startShowOptions.popupOpened"
                       datepicker-options="openDateOptions"
             >
```

Как настроить чтобы при выборе даты не учитывался часовой пояс, то есть время - часы, минуты, секунды были по нолях?
Например вместо "2017-06-08T19:27:15.399Z" было бы "2017-06-07T21:00:00.000Z" и это бы записало мне в базу 2017-06-08 00:00:00 (соответствует "2017-06-07T21:00:00.000Z"). Потому что у меня постоянно расхождения по часовых поясах на разных серверах, то час то два, думаю это бы решило проблему

Answer (score 1):

Вариантом решения проблемы может быть отправка на сервер данных в простом формате (к примеру 2017-02-03), что явно отрезает timezone. Этого можно добиться используя [format()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/) из библиотеки [momentjs](https://momentjs.com). На стороне бекенда принять эту строку и превратить в нужный формат. Решить этот вопрос на стороне сервера будет проще и правильнее, наверное.